# storing list/tuples in sqlite database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a class that holds the size and position of something I draw to the screen.  I am using sqlalchemy with a sqlite database to persist these objects.  However, the position is a 2D value (x and y) and I'd like to have a convienent way to access this as

```
MyObject.pos # preferred, simpler interface

# instead of: 
MyObject.x 
MyObject.y # inconvenient
```

I can use properties but this solution isn't optimal since I cannot query based on the properties

```
session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.pos==some_pos).all()
```

Is there some way to use collections or association proxies to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) (Geometry extended version of [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/)), you can take advantage of that using [GeoAlchemy](http://www.geoalchemy.org/index.html), which allows you to define Column types in terms of geometric primitives available in PostGIS.  One such data type is `Point`, which is just what it sounds like.

PostGIS is a bit more difficult to set up than vanilla PostgreSQL, but if you actually intend to do queries based on actual geometric terms, it's well worth the extra (mostly one time) trouble.

Another solution, using plain SQLAlchemy is to [define your own column types](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#types-custom) with the desired semantics, and translate them at compile time to more primitive types supported by your database.

---

Actually, you could use a property, but not with the builtin `property` decorator.  You'd have to have to work a little harder and create your own, custom descriptor.

You probably want a point class.  A decent option is actually to use
a namedtuple, since you don't have to worry about proxying assignment
of individual coordinates.  The property gets assigned all or nothing

```
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

This would let us at least compare point values.  The next step in
writing the descriptor is to work through its methods.  There are two methods to think about, `__get__`
and `__set__`, and with get, two situations, when called on
an instance, and you should handle actual point values, and when
called on the *class*, and you should turn it into a column expression.

What to return in that last case is a bit tricky.  What we want is something
that will, when compared to a point, returns a column expression that equates
the individual columns with the individual coordinates.  well make one more
class for that.

```
class PointColumnProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ''' these x and y's are the actual sqlalchemy columns '''
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __eq__(self, pos):
        return sqlalchemy.and_(self.x == pos.x,
                               self.y == pos.y)
```

All that's left is to define the actual descriptor class.

```
class PointProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ''' x and y are the names of the coordinate attributes '''
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        assert type(value) == Point
        setattr(instance, self.x, value.x)
        setattr(instance, self.y, value.y)


    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is not None:
            return Point(x=getattr(instance, self.x),
                         y=getattr(instance, self.y))
        else: # called on the Class
            return PointColumnProxy(getattr(owner, self.x),
                                    getattr(owner, self.y))
```

which could be used thusly:

```
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
class MyObject(Base):
    x = Column(Float)
    y = Column(Float)

    pos = PointProperty('x', 'y')
```

Comment: That's a shame, PostGIS is really fantastic for geometric applications.  In any case, any of the other solutions in my answer will work as well in SQLite as with any other DBMS.

Comment: I'm not really doing much with the geometry, so I chose sqlite for its simplicity.  I implemented and tested your suggestion and it works wonderfully!!  Great of you to really flesh it out for me.  The only thing I changed was the assert to a coercion. `if not isinstance(value, Point): value = Point(*value)`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I like this approach and I want to adapt it. But I encountered a little problem. If I may ask: Where does the object `Number` cam from? `from sqlalchemy import Number` didn't seem to help...

Comment: Hmmm.  that's a good question.  I probably meant `Float` or `NUMERIC`.  I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define your table with a PickleType column type. It will then automatically persist Python objects, as long as they are pickleable. A tuple is pickleable.

```
mytable = Table("mytable", metadata,
       Column('pos', PickleType(),
        ...
)
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  There's nothing fundamentally terrible with storing something that aggregates values into a single column, but it should be as portable and versatile as possible.  The next consumer of that same column to come along should be able to use it without too much trouble, and that won't be true with pickled data unless that other program is also written in python.  Instead of pickle, have you considered json?

Comment: This is an interesting option, but I agree with TokenMacGuy that it isn't a good idea to insert pickled data into a database.  json is better, but I'd still like to just have two separate columns in the database and use some sqlalchemy to get objects that present the .pos interface properly.  I feel like it should be possible.